# browserify-shim difference between alias and varName = require("module")

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, browserify, browserify-shim

I'm using `browersify-shim` to bundle jquery, bootstrap, and my custom js files into one final package.

My custom js files don't have any dependency on `jQuery`, although `bootstrap` does.

I've have the following `package.json`

```
"browser" : {
    "jquery": "path/to/jquery",
    "bootstrap": "path/to/bootstrap"
},
"browserify": {
    "transform": [ "browserify-shim" ]
},
"browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "$",
    "bootstrap": {"depends" : "jquery:jQuery"}
},
```

Now in my script file I have to do the following:

```
require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');
```

Is there a difference between adding an alias to "jquery" in `package.json`, vs doing `var window.$ = require('jquery');`

In some places I've seen people are doing both of the above, shouldn't only one be enough?

Secondly, why do I need to explicitly `require` both `jQuery` and `bootstrap`, even if none of my custom js files depend on it. Is there a way to tell `browserify-shim` to just bundle up everything in `package.json`, I'm anyway telling all the dependencies and aliases there. Why the duplicate effort to require each module in my script file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question:

> Is there a difference between adding an alias to "jquery" in package.json, vs doing var window.$ = require('jquery');

The reason people do this is in the case where they need jQuery to be present *outside* their bundle.js. For instance, you might have a `$(document).ready()` handler directly in your index.html, in which case you'd need jQuery available on the `window` object. If you don't have any jQuery code outside of `bundle.js` then this isn't necessary and you can just use `var $ = require('jquery');` as necessary in `bundle.js`.

Your second question makes me think that the above is potentially the case. The answer is you can absolutely load Bootstrap and jQuery outside your `bundle.js`.

A good solution here is to simply add them outside your bundle in the usual way, via a `<script></script>` tag. Then in the event you need them in your bundle, you can [require them as a global](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim#a-expose-global-variables-via-global) so that if you reference them in `bundle.js` they don't get loaded twice.